# Conditionally starting and ending a div using each helper

Tags: ember.js

I am using bootstrap and need to conditionally start a `<div class="row">` depending on the index of the item; in this case, each row has two items.

```
{{#each items as |item index|}}
  {{#if item.isStartRow}}
      <div class="row">
  {{/if}}

  ...my code here

  {{#if item.isEndRow}}
      </div>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

The trouble is that the HTMLBars validates the div has a starting and ending tag, therefore the above will not work.  Can anyone suggest a workaround?

The end result would look something like this if there were 6 items in the array:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">Item 1...</div>
   <div class="col-md-6">Item 2...</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">Item 3...</div>
   <div class="col-md-6">Item 4...</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">Item 5...</div>
   <div class="col-md-6">Item 6...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should be using components and conditionally change tag name based on index or whatever.

Comment: @code-jaff, still not clear.  I have posted the output I require.  Conditionally adding a class will not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's turned out to be a different scenario once you've updated the question, and this is how I'd approach this

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/item-row">
{{#each chunks as |chunk|}}
  <div class="row">
  {{#each chunk as |item|}}    
    <div class="col-md-6">{{item}}</div>
  {{/each}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
</script>
```

JS Component class

```
App.ItemRowComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  chunks : function(){
    var items = this.get('rows.[]').slice(0); // make a copy
    var count = Math.ceil(items.get('length')/2);
    var chunks = [];
    for(var i = 0 ; i < count ; i++){
      chunks.push(items.splice(0,2));
    }
    return chunks;
  }.property('rows.[]')
});
```

[DEMO](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sucuviceve)

You are free to customize child element if you make it as another component. It's an added flexibility.